# Onclick on Main Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried the `onclick` event on parent div which has `100%` the entire portion of div is clickable now. But actually i don't want this because if i did the sub div as pointed to someone function. For example:

```
   <div id="loginContainer" onclick="link();">
    <div id="login_form">
    <form method="post">
<input type="text" name="login" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ddHZb/2/)

When i click to enter the form field also it get it to onclick event. Is there is a way to make a parent div as clickable without affecting the sub div  using javascript or jquery or css.

Thanks

Comment: try with  event.stopPropagation(); in jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [stop the propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) for the form's descendants.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/ddHZb/13/)

```
function link(e) {
    window.open("http://google.com");  
}

$("#login_bar_builder").on("click", link)
                       .on("click", "form *", 
                           function (e) {
                               e.stopPropagation();
                           });
```

Comment: Is the background click working for you in the fiddle? It is not for me.